# A Friend for Today

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Mary was talking to her new friend. She thinks he said,

> Bro, I, um... Avoid Sue! Teenager pill spurn.

Mary says that she probably added extra and can't remember exactly what he said.

**What is Mary's friend's name? What is this puzzle trying to tell you?**

Hint 1:

> When you need help, look to members of this community for guidance.

Comment: Darn downvotes why

Comment: Added extra what?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I noticed that (credits to Jamal Senjaya for the idea):

> The text can be divided into parts: *Bro, I, um*, which is an anagram of `Rubio+M`; *Avoid Sue* which anagrams to `Deusovi+A`; *Teenager pill spurn* which rearranges into `GentlePurpleRain+S`.  Of course, Rubio, Deusovi and GentlePurpleRain are three of our beloved [moderators](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators).

I'm not exactly sure what it means, but here are a few possibilities (edit: The third one has been confirmed correct by the OP):

1. > The extra letters M,A,S can be anagrammed into `SAM`, which sounds like a reasonable name.
2. > The surplus letters are M,A,S and Mary added "X-tra", so that whole thing spells `X-MAS`, which together with a near-homophone of `Mary` says `Merry X-Mas!`.
3. > The text really wants to say `Merry Christmas`, but `Mary` and `MAS` are already here, so the friend's name is what's leftover: `Chris`.
4. > Three moderators are already there, so the friend is Gareth McCaughan, the fourth mod, trying to tell `Merry X-mas` to the other three.

Comment: "Beloved" mods- I laughed at that.

Comment: I think u have the complete answer. +1

Comment: @Sid I mean, I don't know about others, but at least Deusovi seems [fairly popular](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6155/should-we-ban-deusovi-from-puzzle-solving)...

Comment: Your third option is correct. Nicely done!

Answer (score 5):

**Partial Answer**

I think his friend is :

> *Bro, I, um... Avoid Sue!* is anagram for ***Bro, I am Deusovi!***
>  There is extra letter u, maybe for next sentence.

Comment: Why would the answer] address Mary as "bro"?

Comment: @Sid It is weird, but it is still possible that Mary is a man, or maybe it is a clue for christmas.

Comment: "Mary was talking to **her** friend"